# Aligning <iframe> tag to center in HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am trying to align the animation to the center, I have tried using CSS, nothing seems to work, I have even tried adjusting padding and margins to see if any changes happen, but they do not.

https://gyazo.com/b5b6b9f64e01ccfb107a63470ec5a544

In the first Gyazo link it looks centered but below in my screenshot of when i load the web page, it is not centered at all.

https://gyazo.com/f920e6004c39dc19eaadbe5f73abd7ae

Sorry that it's in Gyazo links, I tried to upload the JSFiddle link but I couldn't figure out how to upload the code with all the 4 indents etc, so I hope you have all the needed information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent div needs to be 100% width and to have text align center. The child only needs to think about height/width.

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.child {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
      <iframe class='child' src="https://www.example.com/" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: So I wrote it exactly how you have it, and no changes have been made. It is still stuck on the left side of the page.

Comment: I've added a working example here which you can clone to your machine and run in your browser: https://github.com/AkyunaAkish/align-iframe